# Without contrib, I want to make everything a user does appear to be by someone else. Any comprehensive hook for that?

Tags: users

So, I want to give users an entity reference field of users they may act as.

I'm just not sure of what the best way to do that would be.. Is it lots of hook_presaves?

---

Edit to show general operations

- Node creation / edit
- The flagging User
- [Reply](https://www.drupal.org/project/reply) posts
- All rule conditions / actions ie. "Current User"

I'm beginning to realise this will take a lot of code, which I'm willing to do. I'm just wondering if there's an easy sort of Drupal solution.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what operations you need to change attribution for? It will make a big difference to any possible answer. A node author gets approached in one way, a login record another, and there are any number of other different points that a hook_presave isn’t going to catch, depending on your configuration and installed modules

Comment: I suggest you clone [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) into your custom module, and then remove everything from it you don't need. What is left should be the list of hooks you might be looking for .... no? PS: "***best***" is subjective (a possible reason to close a question), so you may want to replace that part of your question by something like "*possible options to pick from*" ...

Comment: @Clive I edited my answer. Thanks. And Pierre, I was thinking about doing that as my Plan B. The way it works is kinda different to what I need though.. It seems to log you in as another user, but I need the person logged in as themselves (to see all admin and content), and then their actions are as someone else.

Comment: You could start with `hook_entity_presave` as all standard objects in drupal are entities but not sure if all above mentioned operations are handled by entity_presave.

Comment: I totally forgot about _entity_.. I'll try that and see how I get on. Thanks.